# need help speeding up tag cloud filter for IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any ideas on how to speed this up in IE (the filtering process performs decent in Firefox, but almost unusable in IE). Basically, it's a tag cloud with a filter text box to filter the cloud.

```
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){


        $('#tagFilter').keyup(function(e) { 
            if (e.keyCode==8)
            {   
                $('#cloudDiv > span').show();
            }

            $('#cloudDiv > span').not('span:contains(' + $(this).val() + ')').hide(); 
        });

    });
</script>

</head>


<body>
<input type="text" id="tagFilter" />
<div id="cloudDiv" style="height: 200px; width: 400px; overflow: auto;">
<script type="text/javascript">

for (i=0;i<=1300;i++)
{
    document.write('<span><a href="#">Test ' + i + '</a>&nbsp;</span>');
}
</script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

thanks,
rodchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the tags should be unique (it shouldn't make sense to have the tag "awesome" in the cloud twice), give each span an "id" value based on a cleaned-up version of the tag string (replace spaces with underscores, etc etc).  That should make things a **lot** faster, because the filter can just go by "id" value.

In fact, you don't even need a filter: just hide *all* the `<span>` elements in the cloud, and then show the one with the "id" value formed from the current field value. If there isn't one, then there isn't one, but if there is, that'll be very fast.

Comment: Would the selector(s) then change?

Comment: @rod uhh ... the selectors? Oh you mean in the filter?  Yes definitely - you would select just 'span' probably and then `.not('#' + makeTagId($(this).val()))` or whatever. Also like Tgr wrote, don't bother with the ">" thing.

Comment: is there a way to continue to use the "contains" keyword as a user types or does that defeat the purpose of searching by id?

Comment: What would be the point? If you have "id" values, you've got unique identifiers, and that's going to be much better than asking the browser to dig out the DOM contents of the node.

Answer (score 2):

instead of doing 1300 document.writes, try creating a concatenated string and do 1 write.  This may help if it's the document.writes that are slowing down IE.

Comment: I'm sorry for not saying so in OP (just updated it though) but I'm more interested in filtering process performance. But this is still helpful nonetheless. Thanks.

Comment: $('#cloudDiv > span:not(:contains(' + $(this).val() + '))');

Answer (score 1):

As well as what [derek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777493/need-help-speeding-up-tag-cloud-filter-for-ie/2777567#2777567) says, consider using `jQuery's append()` method (or at least the non jQuery equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

- avoid the child selector, it is slow.
- selecting based on contained text is probably even slower. Either use class names to store tag information or build some sort of data structure in javascript (take a look at the jQuery data() function).
- no need to show and then re-hide almost all spans. Use the :visible selector.
- it might help to detach() #cloudDiv and the append() it back after you made your changes.
- you might consider setting a timer on keyup instead of instantly showing/hiding stuff. That way you can wait for the user to finish typing.